# MariaDB (v10.3.29): Unable to update data inside JSON column

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I've a database table which contains a JSON type column. The data the column has is as follows: **(investments column data)**

```
[
  {
    "investor": 1, 
    "amount": 200000, 
    "profit_percentage": 90, 
    "paid": 0
  },
  {
    "investor": 2,
    "amount": 300000,
    "profit_percentage": 80,
    "paid": 0
  }
]
```

What i want is to update the `paid` property inside the data where the specific investor mathces.

What i tried but didn't work:

```
update purchased_vehicles 
     set investments = JSON_SET(investments, "$.paid", '450') 
          where JSON_EXTRACT(investments, '$.investor') = 1
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to use `JSON_SEARCH()` to get the path to the matching array element, then use that in the `JSON_SET()` call.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose to store data in JSON as an array of objects with the same fields? This would be easier to store in a table, with rows instead of an array, and columns instead of object fields. Then the UPDATE would be very simple.

Comment: @Barmar could you kindly provide an example of that. I've tried but failed

Comment: See the question I linked to.

Comment: @Barmar that answer didn't help.

Comment: Can you update the question showing how you tried to use that solution? Then I'll reopen the question and we can try to get it working.

Comment: But I agree with @BillKarwin that the best solution is to use a normalized schema instead of JSON.